# swift3 append function does not work inside of firebase observeSingleEvent

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from the firebase by using an observer. But when I try to append the value into the array that I made before, it fails. Here is the code, Can someone please help me?

```
class ProductTableViewController: UITableViewController{
    var productName:[String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchProduct()
        print(self.productName.count)
    }

    func fetchProduct(){
        let currentUserId = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserId!).child("products").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                self.productName.append("Hello")
        }, withCancel: nil)
    }
```

It should print 1 after I append a value into that array 
but it prints 0.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `print` line and on the `append` line. Now run your code and notice which one is called first.

Comment: This is because Firebase listeners are asynchronous. You should be able to find plenty of examples online, in Swift, on how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know that the Firebase observer is asynchronous, so even if you call it first, it will have to wait for the response. In the meantime your app will continue with the rest of the code, so it will call the print function. If you want to prove it, try putting the print inside the firebase call:

```
class ProductTableViewController: UITableViewController{
var productName:[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchProduct()

}

func fetchProduct(){
    let currentUserId = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserId!).child("products").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.productName.append("Hello")
            print(self.productName.count)
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, it really helps